# In eclipse plugin develop, how to implement a launch config delegate?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have already set tabs like JavaMainTab, JavaArgumentsTab in my LaunchConfigTabGroup. But how to implement the launch config delegate to load those filled configurations and debug/run my project? I hope the launch step is as same as what the default "Java Application" launch does.

Comment: This is far too broad for a Stack Overflow answer. Read all of the [Program launch and debug support](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug.htm) sections in the help.

Comment: Also [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseLauncherFramework/article.html)

Comment: Solved. call super.launch when extends JavaLaunchDelegate.